# Starting a bounty for a question which has a lot of downvotes. Does it deserve a badge?

Tags: discussion

I started a bounty for this question which got 11 downvotes:
[On the subject of "bring up" and "raise"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46355/on-the-subject-of-bring-up-and-raise)

My question is: Is there a badge for a user who starts a bounty on a question which has more than ten downvotes?

If there isn't, do you think that such a badge is needed?

Answer (score 8):

Badges are designed to encourage and reward certain kinds of behaviors in our user community. There is no badge for specifically starting a bounty on a highly-downvoted question, although you can get badges for starting bounties.

A massively downvoted question usually means it is not desired by the community. Putting a bounty on such a question seems like the opposite of something we want to encourage, so it's pretty unlikely that StackExchange management would create a badge for that kind of thing.

So, no and no.